# What does "strictly decreasing point of inflection" mean?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, applications

Since the function is strictly decreasing, how can there be a point of inflection?[image: i have uploaded related context from wikipedia]

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = -x^3$ is strictly decreasing and has an inflection at $x=0$.

Comment: This isn't true, Sana. Look at the graph and you will see the function is nonincreasing on the entire real line. (On the other hand, Robert, I would say that is a 'weakly decreasing point of inflection' since the function is not instantaneously decreasing at zero, just nonincreasing.)

Comment: Thank you very much #Eric. I got this thing clear. f(x)=-x^3 is indeed strictly decreasing function.  I was kind of obsessed with derivative in such a way that i mixed up everything while analyzing and you have already seen how bad the outcome was.

Comment: @EricStucky Look up the definition of [strictly decreasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function).